# adding content to svg with javascript and some cross-browser support

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg, microsoft-edge

I am trying to add an element to an already existing svg file, and it is working fine on chrome and firefox. when i try on edge it does not seem to do anything, all i need is for it to work on up to date versions of the three browsers, but more is always better.

this is how its declared in html

```
 <object data="images/svg/MYSVG.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="svg-object" onload="loadOnClick()"></object>
```

in my loadOnClick call, i try to add an element to it like so

```
var svgObject = document.getElementById('svg-object');
var svgDoc = svgObject.contentDocument;

var tiptext = svgDoc.getElementById('ToolTipText');

let gs = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName('g');


gs[1].innerHTML += '<foreignObject id="homeButton" width="20" height="20" x="10px" y="10px"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style=" fill:#000000;"><a xlink:href="MYOTHERSVG.svg"><path fill="#124A92" d="M7.9,256C7.9,119,119,7.9,256,7.9C393,7.9,504.1,119,504.1,256c0,137-111.1,248.1-248.1,248.1C119,504.1,7.9,393,7.9,256z"></path><path fill="#FFF" d="M408.1,206.8l-150.1-74.9c-1.3-0.6-2.7-0.6-4,0l-150.2,74.9c-1.7,0.8-2.7,2.4-2.7,4.3v29.6c0,1.6,0.8,3.1,2.2,4c1.4,0.9,3.1,1,4.5,0.3l148.2-74l148.1,74c0.6,0.3,1.3,0.5,2,0.5c0.9,0,1.8-0.2,2.5-0.7c1.4-0.9,2.2-2.4,2.2-4V211C410.8,209.2,409.8,207.5,408.1,206.8z"></path><path fill="#FFF" d="M380.5 245.8L256 183.8 131.5 245.8 131.5 360.8 200.5 360.8 200.5 272.6 248 272.6 248 360.8 380.5 360.8z"></path><path fill="#124A92" d="M263.7 272.6H295.7V304.6H263.7z"></path></a></svg></foreignObject>';
```

again, i am unsure why it doesn't seem to work in edge but if you have any ideas let me know!

Comment: That is not the full (but [mcve] form of) the HTML you're using. Having said that, I'm surprised this even works in any browser: modifying an `<object>` would be a pretty big security hole in the same sense that modifying an `<iframe>` without postMessaging would be... so with that said: do you need this SVG image to be a static asset, rather than a normal `<svg>` element on the page? (given that the SVG element is considered a normal element in HTML5)

Comment: mike i just put it into a html file to test and yes this was literally everything needed (apart from the boilerplate stuff for html, and the function brackets for javascript). the svg is interactive and links to other svg files in the page

Comment: Working SVG has become a lot easier now that you can just put it directly on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a Div tag in the foreignObject elements, like this:

```
    <foreignObject id="homeButton" width="20" height="20" x="20" y="20">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style=" widdth:30px; height:30px; fill:#000000;">
          <a xlink:href="MYOTHERSVG.svg">
            <path fill="#124A92" d="M7.9,256C7.9,119,119,7.9,256,7.9C393,7.9,504.1,119,504.1,256c0,137-111.1,248.1-248.1,248.1C119,504.1,7.9,393,7.9,256z"></path>
            <path fill="#FFF" d="M408.1,206.8l-150.1-74.9c-1.3-0.6-2.7-0.6-4,0l-150.2,74.9c-1.7,0.8-2.7,2.4-2.7,4.3v29.6c0,1.6,0.8,3.1,2.2,4c1.4,0.9,3.1,1,4.5,0.3l148.2-74l148.1,74c0.6,0.3,1.3,0.5,2,0.5c0.9,0,1.8-0.2,2.5-0.7c1.4-0.9,2.2-2.4,2.2-4V211C410.8,209.2,409.8,207.5,408.1,206.8z"></path>
            <path fill="#FFF" d="M380.5 245.8L256 183.8 131.5 245.8 131.5 360.8 200.5 360.8 200.5 272.6 248 272.6 248 360.8 380.5 360.8z"></path>
            <path fill="#124A92" d="M263.7 272.6H295.7V304.6H263.7z"></path>
          </a>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </foreignObject>
```

[Note] The inner div should have the xmlns attribute: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`

More detail information, please refer to the following sample code:

```
 <object data="Images/test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="svg-object"></object>
```

SVG content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="svg-object" width="800" height="800" onload="loadOnClick()">
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
        <![CDATA[
            function changeRectColor(evt) {
                var red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
                var green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
                var blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
                evt.target.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ red +","+ green+","+blue+")");
            }      
           function loadOnClick() {
               console.log("hello");
               var svgObject = document.getElementById('svg-object');
               var svgDoc = svgObject.contentDocument;   

               let gs = svgObject.getElementsByTagName('g');   
               gs[1].innerHTML += '<foreignObject id="homeButton" width="20" height="20" x="200" y="200"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style=" fill:#000000;"><a xlink:href="MYOTHERSVG.svg"><path fill="#124A92" d="M7.9,256C7.9,119,119,7.9,256,7.9C393,7.9,504.1,119,504.1,256c0,137-111.1,248.1-248.1,248.1C119,504.1,7.9,393,7.9,256z"></path><path fill="#FFF" d="M408.1,206.8l-150.1-74.9c-1.3-0.6-2.7-0.6-4,0l-150.2,74.9c-1.7,0.8-2.7,2.4-2.7,4.3v29.6c0,1.6,0.8,3.1,2.2,4c1.4,0.9,3.1,1,4.5,0.3l148.2-74l148.1,74c0.6,0.3,1.3,0.5,2,0.5c0.9,0,1.8-0.2,2.5-0.7c1.4-0.9,2.2-2.4,2.2-4V211C410.8,209.2,409.8,207.5,408.1,206.8z"></path><path fill="#FFF" d="M380.5 245.8L256 183.8 131.5 245.8 131.5 360.8 200.5 360.8 200.5 272.6 248 272.6 248 360.8 380.5 360.8z"></path><path fill="#124A92" d="M263.7 272.6H295.7V304.6H263.7z"></path></a></svg></div></foreignObject>';

           }
        ]]>
    </script>
    <g id="firstGroup">
        <rect id="myBlueRect" width="200" height="150" x="120" y="40" fill="blue" onclick="changeRectColor(evt)" />
        <text x="120" y="40" font-size="13px">Click on rectangle to change it's color.</text>
        <foreignObject id="homeButton" width="20" height="20" x="20" y="20">
          <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style=" widdth:30px; height:30px; fill:#000000;">
              <a xlink:href="MYOTHERSVG.svg">
                <path fill="#124A92" d="M7.9,256C7.9,119,119,7.9,256,7.9C393,7.9,504.1,119,504.1,256c0,137-111.1,248.1-248.1,248.1C119,504.1,7.9,393,7.9,256z"></path>
                <path fill="#FFF" d="M408.1,206.8l-150.1-74.9c-1.3-0.6-2.7-0.6-4,0l-150.2,74.9c-1.7,0.8-2.7,2.4-2.7,4.3v29.6c0,1.6,0.8,3.1,2.2,4c1.4,0.9,3.1,1,4.5,0.3l148.2-74l148.1,74c0.6,0.3,1.3,0.5,2,0.5c0.9,0,1.8-0.2,2.5-0.7c1.4-0.9,2.2-2.4,2.2-4V211C410.8,209.2,409.8,207.5,408.1,206.8z"></path>
                <path fill="#FFF" d="M380.5 245.8L256 183.8 131.5 245.8 131.5 360.8 200.5 360.8 200.5 272.6 248 272.6 248 360.8 380.5 360.8z"></path>
                <path fill="#124A92" d="M263.7 272.6H295.7V304.6H263.7z"></path>
              </a>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </foreignObject>
    </g>

    <g id="secondGroup">
        <rect id="myBlueRect" width="200" height="150" x="220" y="220" fill="blue" onclick="changeRectColor(evt)" />
        <text x="220" y="220" font-size="13px">Click on rectangle to change it's color.</text> 
    </g>
</svg>
```

The result as below (using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 version):

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I ended up removing the foreignobject tag and sized in in the viewbox (that worked as well). This is an easier solution, and for that i am grateful